# Grid Column View with Gutter and Repeat Function

Tags: css, sass, gutter

In my app, I am trying to design the page with grid view. I want my app to be optimized for multiple screen sizes and I have information regarding them. For example; `360px width screen has 6 columns, 10px gutter and 18px margin` and, `840px width screen has 12 columns, 12px gutter and 26px margin`. I want to use the `grid-template-columns: repeat(..., ...fr)` function to optimize elements according to screen widths. I couldn't figure out how to achieve this so what should I do to move given screen size properties to repeat function?

Comment: Just write a media query for each screen size and include the grid-template-column property in each one https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.php

Comment: I understand that. But I'm asking where to put those given values inside repeat() function. Such as column number etc.

Comment: Could you edit your question and put your code up please?